# How to keep a floating window from staying in front of screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So I'm using double monitors to code in Visual Studio 2012, and I've been putting files on both windows.

So there will be the main window, where I have my Tools and Toolbars, and on my secondary monitor I have a floating window with only a view of some other files in my solution.

Whenever I click on my main window, it will force my floating window to the front of the screen.

This is a hassle if I am trying do research and apply it to my main window, if I try to click on my main window to make changes, it will force my floating window on my secondary monitor to come to the front and block out whatever page I was researching

Is there a setting I can change in visual studio to keep the floating window from coming to the front whenever I click on my main window?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking for a feature that you are not going to like.  Suppose the floating window is covered by a window of another application.  How are you going to make it visible?   Nothing to click on.  If you have a good suggestion on how to deal with it that doesn't otherwise require a taskbar button for every floating window then submit it to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to enable taskbar buttons for floating windows?

Comment: A taskbar button for floating windows would be perfect. They could even make it optional and off by default. Unfortunately devenv gets worse and worse every year so this will never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible now. In VS 2022 go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Floating Windows

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I found :(